# Understanding RIP relative relocations

Tags: c, assembly, linker, x86-64, elf

I am trying to understand the relocations for the object file generated by this simple program:

```
int answer = 42;

int compute()
{
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    return compute();
}
```

I compile it with simply `gcc -c main.cpp`.

Then, examining `objdump -DCrw -M intel main.o`, we see among other things:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <compute()>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4:   55                      push   rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # e <compute()+0xe>   a: R_X86_64_PC32    answer-0x4
   e:   5d                      pop    rbp
   f:   c3                      ret    

(...)

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <answer>:
   0:   2a 00                   sub    al,BYTE PTR [rax]
    ...
```

We can also look at the relocations as reported by `readelf -rW main.o`:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x250 contains 2 entries:
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
000000000000000a  0000000900000002 R_X86_64_PC32          0000000000000000 answer - 4
(...)
```

Let's look at the relocation for the use of `answer` in `compute()`:

To return `answer` from the function, we have this instruction to put the value of `answer` into `eax`:

```
8:   8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x0]
```

I.e. "copy whatever is at `rip + an offset we don't know yet so let's just put 0s for it for now` into `eax`".

The relocation for that instruction is

```
    Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name + Addend
000000000000000a  0000000900000002 R_X86_64_PC32          0000000000000000 answer - 4
```

The offset value `0xa` means that there's a relocation to be done at `0xa`, or the third byte of the `mov` instruction above which starts on `0x8`. This is the placeholder `00 00 00 00` we saw above. The relocation type is `R_X86_64_PC32`, which according to the [System V Application Binary Interface](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) means "S+A-P", where:

- **S** = the value of the symbol whose index resides in the relocation entry
- **A** = the addend used to compute the value of the relocatable field
- **P** = the place (section offset or address) of the storage unit being relocated (computed using `r_offset`).

The value of the symbol (the value at `0xa`) is `0`. `A` is the addend `-4` on that line.

**I am not certain what `P` is, is it the address of the `.data` section?**

**And where does the `-4` come from?**

**This calculation seems to end up as "4 bytes less the address of the `.data` section". How does that represent the distance from `RIP` (`0xe`) to wherever `answer` ends up in the final executable?**

If I look at the final executable though (`gcc -o main main.o`, `objdump -DCrw -M intel main`), I see our `mov` instruction has been relocated:

```
1131:       8b 05 d9 2e 00 00       mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rip+0x2ed9]
```

The `00 00 00 00` placeholder has been replaced with `d9 2e 00 00`. `rip` is now at `0x1137`, so `rip+0x2ed9` is `0x4010`. And sure enough, at `0x4010` we find the answer:

```
Disassembly of section .data:
(...)
0000000000004010 <answer>:
    4010:       2a 00                   sub    al,BYTE PTR [rax]
```

So everything works out fine in the end, I just don't understand exactly how it happens.

Comment: The `-4` comes from the fact that the cpu uses the updated `rip` for calculation so that already points past the instruction which is 4 bytes from the relocation so the offset needs to be 4 bytes less.

Comment: @Jester: ... because the `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation entry is designed to fill in the relative distance between the target symbol and the *start* of the 4-byte field.  In other cases, like `mov byte [rel32], 123`, the rel32 is still relative to the end of the instruction, but that's another byte past the end of the rel32 itself.  So for example `foo - 5`

Comment: Ok, so when doing the relocation, the linker implicitly knows that relative-to-rip addressing is being used, and will calculate the *distance to S+A-P*, rather than the *address of S+A-P*?