# Interleaved LEA and CALLQ instructions

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly

I've disassembled a function and I'm certain that I know what the function is doing - it's two nested loops that generates multiplication tables. However, there's a section of the assembly that doesn't make sense to me.

```
   0x0000000000000035 <+53>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x3c <main+60>
   0x000000000000003c <+60>:    callq  0x41 <main+65>
   0x0000000000000041 <+65>:    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 0x48 <main+72>
   0x0000000000000048 <+72>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000000004b <+75>:    callq  0x50 <main+80>
   0x0000000000000050 <+80>:    mov    %rax,%rdx
```

Are the `callq` instructions just calling the next instruction, which would have just been called anyway? It also seems like the `rdi` register is being set to the next instruction but is then overwritten by `rax` before anything is done with it.

Is this a common pattern of calls that I should be able to recognize?

Comment: call next-instruction is a sure sign you're looking at a `.o` that hasn't been linked, so the `call rel32` offsets are just `0` placeholders to be filled in by the linker, according to the symbol relocations.  Same for the RIP-relative LEAs.  But this looks like GDB disassembly, without the machine code that would make that extra visible; you ran GDB on a `.o`?  Use `objdump -drwC -Mintel` to annotate with symbol-relocation info.  (The `-Mintel` is optional; you're using AT&T syntax right now.)

Comment: See [Understanding RIP relative relocations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68067522) for an example of what the output should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using the objdump command confirms what I suspected - that these are calls to the IO stream to output the results. I thought that I've disassembled other similar files and seen calls to puts/printf before now, which is what I expected to see here. At least it makes some sense though. The lea calls still don't make sense to me though.

Comment: Are the values in the lea calls also placeholders?

Comment: Yes, note the RIP-relative addressing mode, `[RIP + rel32]`